# how can I convert postgresql array to java array in getJdbcTemplate().query

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I am using spring to interact with postgresql. Here is my problem.

Person have three attributes:

1. name(String)
2. hobbies(String[])
3. gender(boolean)

If I try to get a list of person from database using the method below

```
List<Person> person=  getJdbcTemplate().query("select * from person where name=?",new BeanPropertyRowMapper<person>(Person.class),name);
```

The compiler prompts

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray' to required type 'java.lang.String[]' for property 'hobbies';
```

Is there any way to map pgarray to java array?

Answer (score 0):

By implementing our own RowMapper

```java
public class PersonRowMapper implements RowMapper<Person> {

     Person mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
          Person person = new Person();
          person.setName("nameColumnName");
          person.setGender(rs.getBoolean("genderColumnName"));

          String[] hobbies = (String[]) rs.getArray("hobbies");
          person.setHobbies(hobbies);

          return person;
     }

}
```

Using the above code, we can manually cast the result of `rs.getArray()` into `String[]`.

`RowMapper` helps to provide custom logic to parse the result set into our own object. Use it in place of `BeanPropertyRowMapper` like below:

```java
List<Person> person = getJdbcTemplate().query("select * from person where name = ?", new PersonRowMapper(), name);
```

Comment: Please add more explanation

Comment: @ManuViswam added full example and description. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find how to solve the problem with jdbctemplate + pgArray. So I wrote some fix.
You can use own `ColumnMapRowMapper`.

```
public class ColumnRawMapper extends ColumnMapRowMapper {
        @Override
        protected Object getColumnValue(ResultSet rs, int index) throws SQLException {
            Object obj = rs.getObject(index);
            if (obj instanceof PgArray) {
                return ((PgArray) obj).getArray();
            }
            return super.getColumnValue(rs, index);
        }
    }

Map<String, Object> ggWp = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from temp where ss='3'", new ColumnRawMapper());
```